# undefined in TypeORM and NestJS

Tags: sqlite, nestjs, typeorm

```
 var name = await this.productRepo.findOne({where:{id}})['name']
```

Hi guys. I use typeorm and sqlite to get the property name from `ProductEntity` but I get `undefined` instead.

when I try to run `var name = await this.productRepo.findOne({where:{id}})` i get something like that

```
ProductEntity {
    id: 1,
    name: 'فن لپتاپ',
    code: 'a57gr3f',
    quantity: 2,
    discription: 'ب',
    price: 3000000
```

}
I am expected to get a `فن لپتاپ` instead of undefined
I'll be thankfull if you help.

Answer (score 1):

```js
await this.productRepo.findOne({where:{id}})['name']
//    \____________________________________/
//          this is an instance of Promise, not the resolved value
//          and Promise doesn't have the property 'name'
```

do this instead:

```js
( await this.productRepo.findOne({where:{id}}) )['name']
```

Comment: thankyou for your comment. I've done it with using `var name = await this.productRepo.findOne({where:{id},select:['name']}).then((e)=>{
                                     return e.name
                        })` instead!